# How to concatenate values of two variables in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 variable data frame. I want to concatenates values of these to variables into a new variable using python.
How can I do this?

E.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate columns together with separator:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'F_name':['AA','BB','CC'],
                   'M_name':['dd','ee','ff']})


df['L_name'] = df['F_name'] + '_' + df['M_name']
```

Or use [`str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df['L_name'] = df['F_name'].str.cat(df['M_name'], sep='_')
```

---

```
print (df)
  F_name M_name L_name
0     AA     dd  AA_dd
1     BB     ee  BB_ee
2     CC     ff  CC_ff
```